# Binding converter always return the same value in datatemplate

Tags: c#, binding, converters, datatemplate

I have an ItemsControl bound to an ObservableCollection and in the ViewModelBase there is a property called IsVisible.

I have set an DataTemplate for the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="40,0,50,0" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource MyTextBolckStyle}"
                   Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Width="280"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="2"
                 Height="60"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Text="{Binding IsVisible}"
                 Padding="5,5,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

and this is the Convert method of my BooleanToVisiblityCoverter

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var val = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

        if (val)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return  Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

and this is the strange result I get:

[image]

As you can see every time the IsVisible property is true, the TextBlock visibility is visible and it works fine but every time the IsVisibe property is false, I expect that the visibility of the TextBlock to be collapsed but it seems to me that it is hidden because there is a white space instead of the TextBlock and since I'm working with silver light and there is no Visibility.Hidden enum there, I really don't know what the problem is and I'm confused.

So please help me on this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your converter definition? There is a BooleanToVisibility converter already added in .NET framework 3.0+

**Update:**

I tried your code and it works perfectly here. My guess would be that the problem is not in the code you've posted here but somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not using the .NET framework's but my own converter. it's pretty the same.